# Symfony2 validator not working when file is bigger than post_max_size

Tags: php, symfony

I have set up **upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size** to 32Mb in php.ini.

I am using Symfony2. I have created an entity  that contains a file variable so that people can upload a file:

```
/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="3M")
 */
public $file;
```

- When the file is smaller than 3Mb, the file is correctly uploaded.
- When 3Mb the validator is working fine, displaying the normal error message "file is too big"
- However, when file > 32Mb (post_max_size):

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 150994944 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 62353390 bytes) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Profiler/Profiler.php
>   on line 177

Is there a way to make the validator work when the file uploaded is higher than **post_max_size**? How is Symfony handling file uploads that are bigger than **post_max_size**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an issue about PHP, not Symfony. As you limit POST params size, your submit request does even not "reach" controller.

As post_max_size limit all POST params, including files, **you should define post_max_size higher than upload_max_filesize**.

So now, your question seems to be related to this one : [How to gracefully handle files that exceed PHP's `post_max_size`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133652/how-to-gracefully-handle-files-that-exceed-phps-post-max-size)

Comment: Thanks so much Pece. I think the problem is almost solved. I can now check whether the uploaded file is bigger than post_max_size using $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']. var_dump(POST) and var_dump(FILES) both return array(0){}. However, at the very end, when I want to throw an exception, I still get the Allocation Memory Error. I just don't understand why Apache is trying to allocate a file in the memory even though it is too big (>post_max_size). What should I do? Increasing the memory wouldn't make sense...

Comment: Hi Pece, I can't accept the answer yet because the problem is still not solved :-| I try to find out why the allowed memory size is exhausted even though $_POST and $_FILES are empty... If you have any ideas, that would be awesome. Do you have a trick to debug this type of error? Cheers!

Comment: There is a PHP parameter named 'memory_limit' that defines the max amount of memory a script can consume. Maybe the problem doesn't come from file upload but from what you do with file next to the upload itself... Use memory_get_usage() at many steps of your treatment to know where you use a lot of memory.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and this is quite interesting. memory_get_usage() is always very low. However the size that symfony try to allocate to the memory is the size of the file I upload...and again $_POST and $_FILES are empty. I ended up wondering about symfony itself so I tried a simple code outside symfony and within symfony... It only works outside symfony. I have accepted your answer and will post a new question with the code. Now I am pretty sure it is Symfony related. Symfony might do some stuff with the file on the background.. Thanks very much for your help. :-)

Comment: Here is the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037115/symfony2-allocates-file-to-memory-same-code-tested-outside-and-inside-symfony) if you are interested :-)