# Symfony2: Unable to overwrite 'maxSize' and 'maxSizeMessage' in Image/File constraint

Tags: php, validation, symfony, symfony-2.3

I use this code in my entity class:

```
/**
* @Assert\File(maxSize="8388608", maxSizeMessage="8 MB please")
*/
protected $imageFile;
```

or this one:

```
/**
* @Assert\Image(maxSize="8M", maxSizeMessage="8 MB please")
*/
protected $imageFile;
```

But all i get is this error, when uploading a 5 MB file:

```
The file is too large. Allowed maximum size is 2097152 bytes.
```

My configuration is just ignored.
Weird is that 'mimeTypesMessage=…' is working when i use it in the above examples. This means validation in general is working except of the maxSize/maxSizeMessage stuff.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 validator not working when file is bigger than post\_max\_size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997791/symfony2-validator-not-working-when-file-is-bigger-than-post-max-size)

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed the 'upload_max_filesize' in php.ini which causes this weird behaviour. After setting this to 10M everything worked fine (including the customized error message).