# Image File Size in Php

Tags: php

I am trying to get the file size of an image. If I upload below a 5 MB size image, then this function is properly calculating image size. But if the image file size is exceeded then it is not calculating image file !

$size = filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

I am not understanding what the problem is.

Comment: Check to see that your file_exists() first, incase it has not uploaded correctly

Comment: If uploadsize is exceeded, the file isn't physically available on the server.

Comment: Maximum size limits aside (which are probably what you're running into), the `$_FILES` array already contains the file size in the `'size'` entry; there's no need to call `filesize` yourself.

Comment: I'm guessing the file exceeds your upload limit defined in `php.ini` and you aren't checking the `error` element of the `$_FILES['file']['error']` to see if it failed before trying to get the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

untested code

```
 if(empty($_FILES) && empty($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post'){ //catch file overload error...
        $postMax = ini_get('post_max_size'); //grab the size limits...
        echo "<p style=\"color: #F00;\">\nPlease note files larger than {$postMax} will result in this error!<br>Please be advised this is not a limitation in the CMS, This is a limitation of the hosting server.
        callMyForm(); //bounce back to the just filled out form.
}
elseif(// continue on with processing of the page...
```

Comment: found some post....check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133652/how-to-gracefully-handle-files-that-exceed-phps-post-max-size