# Yii + CuploadedFIle + POST Content-Length of X bytes exceeds the limit of Y bytes in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, file-upload, yii, warnings, max-size

if i use in validation rule for my file to upload

```
array('taskfile', 'file', 'allowEmpty' => true, 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 1)
```

if maxSize < file size < max_pos the correct error displays
but if maxSize < max_post_size < file size then i receive no error messagre but a php warning at the top of my site.

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 41816263 bytes exceeds the limit of 15728640 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

upload_max_filesize and post_max_size are set in the php.ini.
i also tried this workaround with an own vaildation  rule, but it doesnt work either.

```
 public function checkMaxFileSize($attribute) {
    $max_post_size = 1024 * 1024 * ini_get('post_max_size');
    $file_is_too_big = ($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > $max_post_size) ? true : false;

    if ($file_is_too_big)
        $this->addError($attribute, "too big");
```

the error is also display if yii is not in debug mode.

Comment: try the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133652/how-to-gracefully-handle-files-that-exceed-phps-post-max-size)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your post_max_size/upload_max_filesize  in your .htaccess file

```
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
```

Comment: doesnt work. i tried it also with bytes instead of M. both doesnt work.