# How to return error before exceeding post_max_size

Tags: php, post, http-post

How is it possible to throw an error before exceeding `post_max_size` which will return a fatal error?

If php returns a fatal error the whole application will fail and thats not very desirable

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133652/how-to-gracefully-handle-files-that-exceed-phps-post-max-size

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè: Dude! What's wrong with you?