# PHP: Check for dropped/cropped POST-data

Tags: php, post

PHP has several limits on POST-data (overall data size limit as well as field-limits). I currently get no warnings when I run into these limits - except missing data.

Is there a way to check whether PHP ran into one of these limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your error reporting level so that it displays warnings, as a warning is outputted when the POST size is reached.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Setting error_reporting to `E_ALL` includes `E_WARNING`, however you could just use `E_WARNING` if you didn't want other errors to be reported.

If you wanted the errors to be outputted, ensure you have `display_errors` set to `on` or `1`. If you don't, you can do so locally by using `display_errors(1);`

Regardless of whether you displays errors or not, they will still be logged to your PHP error log file.

Answer (score 1):

You can check or change value in `php.ini` or `.htaccess`:

- [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/post_max_size)

There are also another limits in this file:

- [`max_input_nesting_level`](http://php.net/max_input_nesting_level)
- [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/memory_limit)
- [`upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/upload_max_filesize)
- [`max_input_time`](http://php.net/max_input_time)
- [`max_input_vars`](http://php.net/max_input_vars)

You can control these using .htaccess, like so:

```
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

Also check if there are errors during processes using:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Good way to avoid it, but OP is asking how he can catch the warnings as opposed to asking how to increase the size to prevent the errors.

Comment: @Stanyer That said, it seems to me that OP didn't realise you could increase the limits. Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your application can check these settings. Use [ini_get()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) for this.

For example:

```
ini_get('post_max_size'); // in bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that this is a development and **deployment** issue, because your PHP script (even the whole Apache server) may be reverse proxied, and anyway there can be any number of intermediate agents having a limit on the request and thus truncating it.

Thus the first step is ensuring that the PHP limit for post requests size is the least in the chain of server software that handle the request.

Then, I suggest you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2133652/315306) (and answers and comments) to get an idea of what you can do and what the platform gives you, and especially how cumbersome and somewhat unreliable it is to detect such an error.

Anyway, I think you should not be too scared about not giving users feedback about the data entered: after all, everything has a limit (think of database columns size, disk space and so on) and adequate sizing is more important than issuing an error message. At least, I can't even remember the last time a service complained about  the request size. If you are especially interested in file upload limits, instead, that's quite a different thing because it's easier to know, in the PHP script, if the user hit the given limits.