# PHP file uploading and detecting file size

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a form that lets users upload files but I'm having problems detecting files that are too large.

I have the following set in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 20M
```

I understand that the standard way to detect if files are larger than the config file allows is to check `$_FILES['file_name']['error']`. However this only works for me if the actual file is greater than `upload_max_filesize` and smaller than `post_max_size`.

If the actual file size is greater than `post_max_size` then the `$_FILES` variable is removed and I get the log message:

> PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of xxx bytes exceeds the limit of
>   yyy ...

So the question: How do I detect if a user is uploading a file that is greater than `post_max_size`? I need to display a valid user message if this happens.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could check the file size before starting to upload it.
See http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/jquery/HHLN180712-Get-file-size-before-upload-using-jquery.html

Comment: Check out this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133652/how-to-gracefully-handle-files-that-exceed-phps-post-max-size).

Comment: Could you regard the code that you use in uploading?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `set_error_handler()` and check for `E_USER_WARNING` error + appropriate message, and then send it to a user, possibly via throwing an Exception, possibly some other way.

Comment: Also you can use @ to suppress error messages. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: @JhulianoMoreno: But what would you want to put the `@` in front of …? In my understanding this warning is not raised by a specific line of code, but when the script is started …

Comment: This error can't be suppressed, and initial question was that OP wants to actually present this error to a user, not hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$limit = ini_get('post_max_size');
if($filesize > $limit) {
   trigger_error("POST Content-Length of $filesize bytes exceeds the limit of $limit bytes.", E_WARNING);
}
else {
  // upload file
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the $_FILES global is empty if the filesize > post_max_size, so I cannot do this check.