# Hide or get rid of errors because of post_max_size

Tags: php, post

I've a problem with an upload-script in PHP. I've changed `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini to 6M, but I have left `post_max_size` unchanged at 8M. For pictures bigger than 6 MB but smaller than 8 MB, it displays an error message.

What about pictures bigger than 8 MB? I am able to change `post_max_size` in php.ini too, but I would prefer another solution.

I've tried
`echo input type=hidden name=MAX_FILE_SIZE value=6000000`
before `echo input type=file name=datei`
but that doesn't have any effect.

The error I will get with pictures larger than 6M is

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 19639171 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

What can I do? Even `error_reporting(0);` doesn't have any effect on this error message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133652/how-to-gracefully-handle-files-that-exceed-phps-post-max-size