# Slim / PHP post_content_length issues

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to give a user an error if their uploaded file/files exceed the maximum upload size. My `max_upload_size` is working as expected but I'm unable to give any errors when the file exceeds the `post_content-length` due to it just giving me a white screen. Is there any way that I can give errors when a user uploads a file larger than the max post length?

My current configuration:

`max_upload_size = 128M`

`post_content-length = 128M`

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/q/2133652/6712884](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2133652/6712884). That answer seems to be correct.